# Validate merge has been performed with tortoise/svn and TeamCity

Tags: merge, tortoisesvn

We're using TortoiseSVN and TeamCity, and the project have now a trunk and a branch (*trunk* and *release201301*). Sometimes, not often, the developers forget to merge our changes in the *realese201301* down to *trunk* - which of course can cause all sort of problems at some stage.

Anyone knows a tool or technique for validating when a Commit has been merged from a (or many) branch(es) to some other branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In recent TortoiseSVN versions, each merge step your team perform is registered into a special property called `svn:mergeinfo`. You just need to check if the revisions from the branch that should be merged are registered into this property (you can use <kbd>SVN Log</kbd>, <kbd>SVN Revision Graph</kbd> or other features, at your discretion).